# Elasticsearch Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run elasticsearch on windows by following [this tutorial](https://newsinfo-blog.blogspot.pt/2016/05/install-elasticsearch-on-windowwamp.html).
When i run bin/elasticsearch.bat i did get this message:

```
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms${packaging.elasticsearch.heap.min}

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I tried inceasing memory from java by setting [like this](http://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7).
Then i removed `%JAVA_OPTS%` from elasticsearch.bat line:

> "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" %JAVA_OPTS% %ES_JAVA_OPTS% %ES_PARAMS% -cp
>   "%ES_CLASSPATH%" "org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch" start
>   !newparams!

Now i get this message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
```

I'm running java last version jre1.8.0_144 x64 and elastic version 2.4.6.
In the elasticsearch in wamp tutorial it says

> Now open 'elasticsearch.bat' file in 'C:\elasticsearch-2.3.2\bin\'
>   directory

But in the zip files is located in

> C:\elasticsearch-2.4.6\distribution\src\main\resources\bin

Even in 2.3.2 is located in same directory. I don't know if it makes any diference.

I have no ideas what else can i change. Any help would be nice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il looks like you are trying to launch the *.bat* script from a source distribution, that is the set of source files accompanying the binary distribution of ElasticSearch (the one you can run).

The *src/main/resources* path is typically used in java software projects to host resources that should be copied to the distribution archive, so *src/main/resources/bin/elasticsearch.bat* should be available at path *bin/elasticsearch.bat*.

If you really need ElastiSearch 2.4.6 you could:

- download it from https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/distribution/zip/elasticsearch/2.4.6/elasticsearch-2.4.6.zip
- decompress the archive and launch the script at relative path *elasticsearch-2.4.6\bin\elasticsearch.bat*

Comment: I'm gonna try it. Where did you get that file? I went to elastics website, and then downloads. Then choosed version 2.4.6 "https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-2-4-6".

Comment: Glad to know it works for you. The link I pasted came exactly from the steps you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

disclaimer: I am not a windows user, so I probably cant help fully. But what you are seeing is the wrong configuration of the heap size. The line above

```
-Xms${packaging.elasticsearch.heap.min}
```

should be something like `-Xms2g` (for two gigabytes of heap). It seems some configuration service did not work as expected for the package you downloaded. You can check the `elasticsearch.in.bat` or just search for `packaging.elasticsearch.heap.min` to check where this is set and set it to whatever heap you want to assign to ES.

Comment: Davide Cavestro answer solved the problem. I did set -xms4g before. Thank you